# How to test for basic Javascript Errors on Web Page load

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, automated-tests, functional-testing

What ways are there for automated testing if a Page (URL) loads without Javascript Errors?

Background: I'm a big fan of bare bones testing. For Server Side code we use [a simple script](https://github.com/mdornseif/appengine-toolkit/blob/master/examples/tests/resttest.py) which basically hits every URL once. This together with tools like [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) and [pylint](http://www.pylint.org) already catches most errors inherent to dynamic languages. We only write specific tests if find errors during manual testing.

I like to extend this approach to front-end code mostly written in React+Redux. It seems static checking with [eslint](http://eslint.org) does not detect many basic errors. So I want to automatically deploy to a server and then automatically test for each relevant URL if the page loads without errors in the browser. Automatic Deployment works nice with app engine

Something like

```
checkjs -u user -p password http://example.com/firstapp
checkjs -u user -p password http://example.com/secondapp
```

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) seems to be way to go. OR maybe [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). But everything build around it seems to be aimed at TDD, unit-testing and not end-to-end testing.

So I'm not looking for a ready made tool but for patterns and approaches. I't can't be that I'm the first and only person looking for the most elegant way to check javascript inside the DOM for basic errors by executing a DOM `onload()` etc.

How would I approach such an endeavour without reinventing everything form scratch.

Comment: You *could* do that with PhantomJS, but this would probably show you errors that are not really there, because the engine is quite old.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic. After extensive research into end-to end testing I found no obvious way to do it without significant complexity. This is not asking for a link, but asking for a way to archive a specific testing task.

Comment: *"Is there something available to do easy detection of JS errors during page load?"* This reads to me like you're asking for a tool. Even if you didn't phrase it like that it would still be a tool request. Yes, you could do that with PhantomJS (as I noted in my previous comment). You could do that with some other browser driven through selenium. You could use some other standalone browser. You could use a JavaScript emulator/engine directly. There are simply too many possible answers.

Comment: So there seems no current established best practice to test for simple page loading JS errors. I'm surprised.